# How to get "Entry" and "Exit" message on geospatial analytics in IBM bluemix

Tags: angularjs, ibm-cloud, geospatial, iot

I am working on IBM Bluemix IOT application.I created devices and I am getting maps successfully. I created geospatial analytics service in bluemix also. In maps I am able to create geofence. When car enters geofence it is successfully giving entry message. But when car exits ,its not showing exit message.

```
Subscriptions.geoAlerts = new Subscription(window.config.notifyTopic, function(msg) {
        if (!msg.destinationName.match(window.config.notifyTopic)) { return; }
        try {
            var data = JSON.parse(msg.payloadString);
            console.log(data);
            var id = data.deviceInfo.id;
//JR: Custom GEO notification
            //var text = data.eventType;
            var text = "Entry";

            var fgColor = "white"; 
            var bgColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)"; 
            var duration = 2000;

            var c = demo.getCar(id);
            if (c) {
                c.addOverlay(text, duration, bgColor, fgColor);
            }
            /*
            var id = data.id;
            var text = data.text;
            var fgColor = data.fgColor || "black"; 
            var bgColor = data.bgColor || "rgba(255,255,255,0.9)"; 
            var duration = data.duration || 3000;

            var c = demo.getCar(id);
            if (c) {
                c.addOverlay(text, duration, bgColor, fgColor);
            }
            */
        } catch (e) { console.error(e.message); }
    });
```

the above MQttClient.js I am using . Can any one give me suggestions highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Paul's answer... if you haven't done so, make sure to specify:

```
"notifyOnExit" : "true",
```

on your call to the addRegion API.

Answer (score 0):

The code as shown will display "Entry" for all events received including entry and exit events (as well as "hang out" events if the monitored region is configured for hangout detection). You should be using `data.eventType` as shown in the commented line of code (line 8) above.

Comment: "data.eventType" is returning null. Thats why I manually assigned  to "Entry" .

Comment: If eventType is missing there's something else wrong. I'm assuming the `msg` parameter being passed to the function is the json payload from the message received from the `mqtt_notify_topic` specified when you started the Geospatial Analytics service. Also, just to make sure, the `mqtt_notify_topic` must be different from the `mqtt_input_topics`.

Each event message received from the Geospatial Analytics service will contain the eventType field.

Comment: Each event message sent by the Geospatial Analytics service will look like:

    `{
       "deviceInfo": {
          "id": "64",
          "location": {
             "latitude": 36.1356304,
             "longitude": -115.1502579
          },
          "originalMessage": "{\"ID\":64,\"lon\":-115.1502579,\"lat\":36.1356304,\"heading\":\"271.478\"}"
       },
       "eventType": "Exit",
       "regionId": "Tracking Path",
       "time": "13:19:21"
    }`